# Only select records between start and end time and date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a school project where I have to make a todo web app. now i have a little problem. I need to get the records that are running out of time (think 20% of the whole task left). now i'm looking for a solution in php or a sql statement with which i can retrieve only those records.

I tried many statements but i cant get one to work.

```
SELECT * FROM tasks
                    WHERE user_id='$user_id'
                    AND '$currentDate' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

The above one is working with the date but not with time.

So now I need to have a statement or function that only retrieves the tasks that are almost finished. I've added a screenshot of the database and the application to clarify it a bit.

i hope someone could help me. (this is my first time using stackoverflow so sorry if i do something wrong)

[image: app]

[image: database]

Comment: Please share more details - what **exactly** is not working? Can you share sample data, and the expected output for that data? How does that date condition refer to "records that are running out of time"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should not be munging your query with constants, date or otherwise.  So, use `now()`.

Second, combine the date/time into a single column

Third, you seem to want `and`:

```
WHERE user_id = ? AND
      NOW() >= start_datetime AND
      NOW() < end_datetime
```

If you want to store the date/time in separate columns, then you can combine them:

```
WHERE user_id = ? AND
      NOW() >= ADDTIME(CAST(start_date as DATETIME), start_time) AND
      NOW() < ADDTIME(CAST(end_date as DATETIME), end_time)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, thats working great! Do you have any idea how i can select the records where only 20% of the time between the start and end date/time is left?

Comment: @sandeeeerr . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a new question, you should ask it as a *new* question, with appropriate explanation, sample data, and results.